# Program with multiple methods that finds and average

Tags: java, methods

This is my first time writing multiple methods and I need a program that will take some double values input by the user and find the average. This is what I have attempted so far and it prints out:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException     
> at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)  
> at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)     
> at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)     
> at Lab5.main(Lab5.java:11)
> ```

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lab5
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    double sum = scan.nextDouble();
    count = scan.nextInt();
    printLineAverage(sum, count++);

}

    public static void printLineAverage(double sum, int count)
    {
        double average =  sum/count;
        System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `printLineAverage()` method does not print (output) anything. So it's `calculateAverage()`. Your `main` method does not print anything either.

Comment: @PM 77-1 Alright, I've edited it a couple times and I cannot get anything to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @gdhc21 Check the update to my answer.

Comment: @gdhc21 please update the error you are getting along with the line number.

Comment: @gdhc21 Check update on my original answer to remove error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need to display result somewhere right!! Have you done that??

Add `System.out.println(printLineAverage(sum, count++));` to display result of your printLineAverage method.

**Update**: Change your main method to

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        double sum = scan.nextDouble();
        count = scan.nextInt();
        printLineAverage(sum, count++);

    }
```

And when you input value for `count` remember it has to be `int`(not containing decimals). In case you want to extend your code to handle double inputs as well change the type of `count` from `int` to `double`

Comment: This is a **comment** - not an answer.

Comment: I edited it a bit and still can't figure it out, but thanks for pointing out the lack of a print statement.

Comment: @Prateek I see too may results actually. It will continuously print answers

Comment: See my update. You are having too many results because of the `while` loop. Change your `main method` with what I have posted and it will work just fine.

Comment: @Prateek It gives me an Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException error. Could it be the count integer? It's just supposed to be the total number of doubles input by the user.

Comment: If you are using the code you have in your question with my main method it will try that!!

Comment: @Prateek I did that and I still get the exception

Comment: Can you replace the code in the question with the one you are currently using and getting exception

Comment: Why on Earth do you want to calculate the average of a **single** value?

Comment: This is what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
System.out.println(printLineAverage(sum, count++));
```

Comment: I edited it a bit and still can't figure it out, but thanks for pointing out the lack of a print statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a **loop** to get more than one value. Then when user (for example) enters  some characters that are not numeric, you stop accepting input and calculate and print the average.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;

    while (scan.hasNextDouble()) { 

      sum +=  scan.nextDouble();
      ++ count;

    }

    scan.close();
    printLineAverage(sum, count);
}
```

If you want user first to enter a number of numeric values he plans to enter, then you will need to get value for `count` and use `for(int i=1, i<=count, ++i)` loop to total the doubles.

Comment: It will only give me the average if I exit out of the program manually (ctrl+c) is there a way I could fix this?

Comment: **No**. You have not read my first paragraph. Enter `stop` or any other character combination which is not a number to end entry.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you input a double value for the count when you are expecting an int value in the program. Other than that your code is working fine.

Change `count = scan.nextInt();` to `count = scan.nextDouble();` and change the type of count to double